# How to compare multiple strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, compare, string-comparison, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void fun1(void);
void func1()
{
  printf("Function1 executed \n");
}
int main()
{
  char syscom[256];
  char check[] = "cmd";
  do 
  {
    printf("Enter function : ");
    fflush (stdout);
    scanf("%255s",syscom);
    int numb;
    numb = strcmp("funct1",syscom);
    printf("%d\n",numb);
    if (numb == 1)
    {
      func1();
    }
  }while(strcmp("quit",syscom) != 0);
  return 0;
}
```

For some reason strcmp runs fine in the do-while loop however inside the actual loop where you are given a choice of which function it returns 1 always. For example in the Enter function part, even if type in a random string, it generates 1 not 0 like I want it to. I know c++ would make this program a breeze, but I want this on c.

So i put the title as multiple strings as the program is going to have multiple functions, these weren't included as I have no idea how to use strcmp on multiple functions.

Comment: `numb = strcmp("funct1", syscom)` would set `numb` to `0` if there's a match, `1` if your entered string is alphabetically after `"funct1"`, and -1 if it is before.

Comment: Based on your description, you want `if (numb == 0)`, not `if (numb == 1)`. `strcmp()` returns `0` if the string match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
numb = strcmp("funct1",syscom);
printf("%d\n",numb);
if (numb == 1) {
  func1();
}
```

to this:

```
numb = strcmp("funct1",syscom);
printf("%d\n",numb);
if (numb == 0) {
  func1();
}
```

Next time you post a question please see the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) first:

> returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
>   return value    indicates:

1. <0  the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1
   than in ptr2
2. 0   the contents of both strings are equal
3. >0 the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2